# Rf receiver, change timer

Tags: arduino-uno, timers, rf

I need some help. I use function rx_setup()  оf library VirtualWire.h which is used to transmit information wirelessly. The function use timer аnd there is  conflict with any of the other libraries. Does anyone know how I can change the timer, which uses function?

This is the function:

```
void vw_setup(uint16_t speed)
{
    uint16_t nticks; // number of prescaled ticks needed
    uint8_t prescaler; // Bit values for CS0[2:0]

#ifdef __AVR_ATtiny85__
    // figure out prescaler value and counter match value
    prescaler = _timer_calc(speed, (uint8_t)-1, &nticks);
    if (!prescaler)
    {
        return; // fault
    }

    TCCR0A = 0;
    TCCR0A = _BV(WGM01); // Turn on CTC mode / Output Compare pins disconnected

    // convert prescaler index to TCCRnB prescaler bits CS00, CS01, CS02
    TCCR0B = 0;
    TCCR0B = prescaler; // set CS00, CS01, CS02 (other bits not needed)

    // Number of ticks to count before firing interrupt
    OCR0A = uint8_t(nticks);

    // Set mask to fire interrupt when OCF0A bit is set in TIFR0
    TIMSK |= _BV(OCIE0A);

#elif defined(__arm__) && defined(CORE_TEENSY)
    // on Teensy 3.0 (32 bit ARM), use an interval timer
    IntervalTimer *t = new IntervalTimer();
    t->begin(TIMER1_COMPA_vect, 125000.0 / (float)(speed));

#else // ARDUINO
    // This is the path for most Arduinos
    // figure out prescaler value and counter match value
    prescaler = _timer_calc(speed, (uint16_t)-1, &nticks);
    if (!prescaler)
    {
        return; // fault
    }

    TCCR1A = 0; // Output Compare pins disconnected
    TCCR1B = _BV(WGM12); // Turn on CTC mode

    // convert prescaler index to TCCRnB prescaler bits CS10, CS11, CS12
    TCCR1B |= prescaler;

    // Caution: special procedures for setting 16 bit regs
    // is handled by the compiler
    OCR1A = nticks;
    // Enable interrupt
#ifdef TIMSK1
    // atmega168
    TIMSK1 |= _BV(OCIE1A);
#else
    // others
    TIMSK |= _BV(OCIE1A);
#endif // TIMSK1

#endif // __AVR_ATtiny85__

    // Set up digital IO pins
    pinMode(vw_tx_pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(vw_rx_pin, INPUT);
    pinMode(vw_ptt_pin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(vw_ptt_pin, vw_ptt_inverted);
}

#endif // ARDUINO

// Start the transmitter, call when the tx buffer is ready to go and vw_tx_len is
// set to the total number of symbols to send
```